# Why does the parent element of source tag need to be amp-video?

Tags: amp-html, amp-img

On the amp docs https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/validation_errors
it says that source requires a media tag (`amp-audio`, `amp-video`, etc.).

I have a picture tag with multiple source elements but when I try to transform it to `amp-img` I get the error that it needs to be `amp-video`.

Do you know why it doesn't accept `amp-img` as its parent element?
Is it not considered to be a media tag.

Comment: difficult to offer advice without seeing source code

Comment: The original HTML, the picture tag was missing the required img element. So in that case, we skipped the malformed element but in case where there is a picture element with multiple source and an img tag we converted to an amp-img with the right src and srcset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to define different image URLs for certain resolutions/sizes. Have a look at the *srcset* attribute of `<amp-img>`.
There's an example here:

https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-img/

Comment: Correct, in the end we used the source elements for the srcset attribute of amp-img.